# Удаление записи из таблицы

Tags: java

Скажите, а можно ли этот фрагмент переделать, чтобы удалялась только одна выбранная строка из таблицы? Создана `DefaultTableModel` и передана в `JTable`

```
class Udalenie1 implements ActionListener{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int rows = model8.getRowCount();
        for (int i=rows-1;i>=0;i--) {
            model8.removeRow(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, как-то так: ( если table - это JTable )

```
model.removeRow(table.getSelectedRow());
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь)

Comment: @Slava, если Вам помог мой ответ - отметьте его правильным.